# SwiftUI: How to populate a dict with a for-loop?

Tags: swift

Working on a bill splitting app and I am trying to create a dict with the amount everyone has to pay, e.g.:

```
{
"Person 1": 20,
"Person 2": 50,
"Person 3": 30
}
```

For now I am going for an even split by running this:

```
var dataDict: [String: Int] {
    let numberOfPeople = 5
    let billTotal = 100
    let costPerPerson = billTotal / numberOfPeople
    var dict: [String: Int] = [:]
    
    ForEach(1 ..< numberOfPeople+1) { number in 
        dict["Person \(number)"] = costPerPerson
    }
    return dict
}
```

However I am getting the following error on the ForEach:

> Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

What exactly am I doing wrong and how could I populate the dict with the for loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ForEach` is not a for-loop in Swift. It's a View out of SwiftUI. The syntax you mean here is:

```
for number in 1...numberOfPeople {
    dict["Person \(number)"] = costPerPerson
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That did it, didn't know there was a difference between ForEach and for.